# Node.js Outlook calendar REST return 500 (internal server error)

Tags: node.js, rest, email, calendar, outlook-restapi

I'm attempting to replicate Outlook's REST API tutorial so I can access a list of calendar events. I've literally just followed line by line with the tutorial found here: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/node
(Direct complete project used here as well with the same issue: https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-tutorial)

I am able to connect to an Outlook account, but upon trying to GetEvents (or mail, or contacts), I am met with the following error:

```
getEvents returned an error: REST request returned 500; body:
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerTransientError","message":"An
internal server error occurred. Try again later."}}
```

I've attempted using this on multiple computers (PC and MAC), over different networks, and with different Outlook accounts to no avail. Account tokens are being grabbed correctly, and there doesn't appear to be any issues with the API ID or password. Does anyone have any inkling with what might be going wrong? Is this an issue on Outlook's end? It seems unlikely.

Comment: Something else that may be helpful would be if anyone else can get the tutorial working?

Comment: I ran into the same problem (doing the Django tutorial).  I received the 500 error trying to use the Calendar API.  I then went to the Outlook Oauth Sandbox.  The Sandbox worked for the sample account, but it didn't work for mine.  I'm starting to suspect that my account hasn't been activated for REST API.  Of course, I thought that you receive a specific error when that's the case (as opposed to just a 500 error), but who knows, maybe the 500 error indicates that too.